# Accessing trace log of wso2 stratos live deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos, wso2-esb

I wish to access the trace log of my WSO2 ESB proxy which i deployed to Stratos live. I need a trace log file which will be available for our local in ESB_HOME/repository.logs folder.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

No Currently we don't have the functionality to view trace logs of ESB in Stratoslive.It will be available soon in our next versions.
However you can view system logs by going to
Monitor--> System Logs